# Why can't I change the value in custompipe?

Tags: nestjs

I am learning nestjs.
The docs say as below.

1. transformation: transform input data to the desired form (e.g., from string to integer)
2. validation: evaluate input data and if valid, simply pass it through unchanged; otherwise, throw an exception when the data is incorrect

Why isn't the code working?

```
// pipe
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    const test = parseInt(metadata.data);
    return test;
  }
}
```

```
// controller
 @Get('/123')
  test(@Query('content', CustomPipe) content: number) {
    console.log('content', content);
    console.log(typeof content);
    const test = '1234';
    console.log('parseint ', parseInt(test));
  }
```

request url
http://localhost:3001/123?content="1234"

console.log result
content NaN
number
parseint  1234

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be parsing `metadata.data`. You need to do `parseInt(value)`. `metadata.data` is the string that is passed to the decorator, in this case it is the string `'content'`, which obviously doesn't `parseInt()`.

Comment: Is it okay to do parseInt(value) instead of parseInt(data.value)?
I don't quite understand. Isn't the role of PIPE a data format conversion?

Comment: A pipe takes in two parameters, `value`, the value that is originally handed to the `@Query()`/`@Param()`/`@Body()` decorator, and metadata, which contains information like "Is the pipe being ran against query params" or "What is the type of the @Body() decorated parameter". The `metadata.data` is "what string was passed to the decorator", in your case it's the string `'content'`. What you're trying to do is transform the `value` sent in to actually be a number and not a string, so `parseInt(value)` is fine and exactly what you should be doing